# Tricky `FindRoot/NExpectation` problem

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

What's the best way to solve the following with $x\sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$?

$$E_x[\log(1-2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4)]=0$$

Idea 1: `FindRoot`

```
a0 = 2.42;
term[a_] := 
  TransformedDistribution[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4], 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]];
FindRoot[NExpectation[t, t \[Distributed] term[a]], {a, a0}]
(* NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy *)
```

Idea 2: increase `MaxRecursion`, `AccuracyGoal`

```
a0 = 2.42;
method = {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 30, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 12}};
term[a_] := 
  TransformedDistribution[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4], 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]];
FindRoot[
 NExpectation[t, t \[Distributed] term[a], Method -> method], {a, a0}]
(* {a -> 2.42125 - 2.16855*10^-9 I} *)
```

Idea 3: look at density to find tricks

```
a0 = 2.42;
func = With[{a = a0}, 
   PDF[TransformedDistribution[Log[1 - 2 a x^2 + a^2 x^4], 
     x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]]];
Plot[func[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Now it seems an integral splitting technique would work, but I can't get PDF for symbolic $a$, any ideas?

Background: this gives largest $a$ such that $w=w-a w x^2$ converges almost surely for any starting $w$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Part 1.** Using $1-2ax^2+a^2x^4 = |1-ax^2|^2$ and the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician):

```
pdfN01=1/Sqrt[2*Pi]*Exp[-x^2/2];
expectationAux:=Integrate[2*Log[Abs[1-a*x^2]]*pdfN01,{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]//FullSimplify;
expectation=Piecewise[{
    {Assuming[a>0,expectationAux],a>0},
    {Assuming[a<0,expectationAux],a<0}},0];
(*
Piecewise[{
  {2*(-EulerGamma + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, -1/2*1/a]/a + Log[a/2]), a > 0}, 
  {2*(-EulerGamma + Pi*Erfi[1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[-a])] + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, -1/2*1/a]/a + Log[-1/2*a]), a < 0}},
0]
*)
```

Plot of the result:

```
Plot[expectation,{a,-3,8},WorkingPrecision->100,AxesLabel->{"a","Expectation"}]
```

[image]

**Part 2.** Determine the $a\approx 2.5$ where the expectation vanishes:

```
FindRoot[expectation,{a,25/10},WorkingPrecision->100]
(* a->2.421249521036836042992780131428225933128842834067867847377838424345397835692066559296652232682365322 *)
```

Comment: Neat trick with Piecewise, learning something new every day!