# Computing statistics of sample average over $n$ IID variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I need to plot $E[\log|1-a X|]=0$ as a function of $a$ where $X$ is sample average of $n$ IID draws from standard $\chi$^2. The following is a symbolic approach (borrowed from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272403/217)) which works for $n=1$ and $n=2$ but breaks down for higher values.

What is the nicest way to get this plot for higher values of $n$?

The obstacle is that PDF of chi-squared sample mean doesn't evaluate for $n>2$, hence need an automatic way of constructing the appropriate integral, tips?

```
(* distribution of average of n chi-squared variables *)
sampleAverage[n_] := (
   xvec = Array[x, n];
   varspec = 
    Table[x[i] \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1], {i, 1, n}];
   TransformedDistribution[Mean[xvec], varspec]
   );
n = 2;
SF = StringForm;
pdf = PDF[sampleAverage[n], x];
expectation = 
  Assuming[a > 0, 
   Integrate[Log[Abs[1 - a*x]]*pdf, {x, 0, Infinity}]];
Plot[expectation, {a, 0, 8}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  SF["zero crossing for n=`` at a=``", n, 
   a /. First@FindRoot[expectation, {a, 25/10}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: "The obstacle is that PDF of chi-squared sample mean doesn't evaluate 
for n>2." Not true : `t = Table[{n, FullSimplify[
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[i], {i, n}]/n, Table[x[i] \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[1], {i, n}]], z], Assumptions -> z > 0]}, {n, 1, 8}]`.  You'll find that the general pdf can be defined as `pdf[n_, z_] := Exp[-z n/2] z^(n/2 - 1) n^(n/2)/(2^(n/2) Gamma[n/2])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can find an expression for $E[\log|1-a X|]$ for $n=2,3,4$ using `Integration` but `NIntegration` appears necessary for $n>4$.

The pdf for the mean of $n$ $\chi^2_1$ independent random variables is given by

```
pdf[n_?IntegerQ, z_] := Exp[-z  n/2] z^(n/2 - 1) n^(n/2)/(2^(n/2) Gamma[n/2])
```

The means of $\log|1-a X|$ for $n=2,3,4$ are found as follows:

```
mean[n_?IntegerQ, a_] := FullSimplify[
  Integrate[Log[1 - a  z] pdf[n, z], {z, 0, 1/a}, Assumptions -> a > 0] +
  Integrate[Log[a  z - 1] pdf[n, z], {z, 1/a, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0], Assumptions -> a > 0]

m2 = mean[2, a]
(* -E^(-1/a) ExpIntegralEi[1/a] *)

m3 = mean[3, a] // Simplify
(* 2 - EulerGamma - (3 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {1/2, 2}, -(3/(2 a))])/a + Log[a/6] *)

m4 = mean[4, a] // Simplify
(* 1 - ((2 + a) E^(-2/a) ExpIntegralEi[2/a])/a *)
```

To solve for values of $a$ that make the means equal to zero:

```
Solve[m2 == 0, a][[1]]
(* {a -> 2.68451} *)
FindRoot[m3 == 0, {{a, 2}}]
(* {a -> 2.69888} *)
FindRoot[m4 == 0, {{a, 2}}]
(* {a -> 2.663} *)
```

For larger values of $n$ numerical integration seems necessary:

```
n0 = 500;
FindRoot[(NIntegrate[Log[1 - a z] pdf[n0, z], {z, 0, 1/a}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] + 
 NIntegrate[Log[a z - 1] pdf[n0, z], {z, 1/a, ∞}] // Quiet) == 0, {{a, 2.6}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Quiet
(* {a -> 2.00808} *)
```

It looks like $a \rightarrow 2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! How did you get the PDF?

Comment: From the table created in my comment in your post, I saw that each pdf was a multiple of $z^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \exp \left(-z n/2\right)$.  Then the coefficient to make the pdf integrate to 1 was found with `1/Integrate[Exp[-z  n/2] z^(n/2 - 1), {z, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> n > 0]`.

Comment: OK, ChatGPT was useful here, sum of chi-squared is another chi-squared, so alternative way is to do use PDF of `TransformedDistribution[x/n, 
 x \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[n]]`

Comment: That's even better.  (I should have done it that way.)