# Switching order of integration/differentiation gives numerical noise

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm doing a relatively straightforward change of integration/differentiation and getting unexpected results in Mathematica. IE, the function is fairly smooth, but the derivative I get using this method is numerical noise .... any idea why this fails?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int f(a,z) \mathrm{d}z = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(a,z) \mathrm{d}z $$

```
f[a_] = Log[(1 - a z)^2] E^(-z/2)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[z]);
Plot[NIntegrate[f[a], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}], {a, 0, 3}]

df[a_] = D[f[a], a];
Plot[NIntegrate[df[a], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}], {a, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

I expected the second graph to look more like the one below, obtained using symbolic integration from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272403/217)

```
dg[a_] = 
  D[2*(-EulerGamma + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, -1/2*1/a]/a +
       Log[a/2]), a];
Plot[dg[a], {a, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that first plot `Plot[NIntegrate[f[a], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}], {a, 0, 3}]` also has a noise. It means that we need some method of integration like this one

```
f[a_] = Log[(1 - a  z)^2]  E^(-z/2)/(Sqrt[2  \[Pi]]  Sqrt[z]);
Plot[NIntegrate[f[a], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {a, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

For derivative we have exact expression

```
D[f[a], a]

Out[]= -((E^(-z/2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[z])/(1 - a z))
```

Therefore, function `f'[a]` has singularity on the line `1-a z==0`. To integrate this function we use special method

```
Plot[NIntegrate[-((E^(-z/2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[z])/(1 - a z)), {z, 
   0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
  Exclusions -> {1 - a  z == 0}, MinRecursion -> 4, 
  MaxRecursion -> 20], {a, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Maybe I'm missing theory, but why do I need to use PrincipalValue method here? It's used for infinite integrals, right? Clearly the derivative is not infinite

Comment: Function `f'[a]` has singularity on the line `1-a z==0`, it is why we use `Method -> "PrincipalValue"`.  See tutorials on `Compatibility/tutorial/NumericalMath/CauchyPrincipalValue`